# How to add more than one scheme in xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode5, xcodebuild, xcode-workspace, xcode-scheme

I mm building xcode workspace in terminal only (xcodebuild - Internal build). It has five schemes. But, at a time I can build only one scheme. I would like to build all the scheme at a time. A single workspace may have more than one scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a single workspace may have multiple schemes but they all must be built independently - it's not possible to build all schemes at a time.

There's an `xcodebuild` option: `-alltargets` that might be helpful - because schemes are based on targets - however I'm not sure it's useful for this case.